# JProgressBar Changing Bar Color

Tags: java, user-interface, jprogressbar

I ve been trying to change the jProgressBar Colour, but keeps being orange

*Here are the properties*
[image: properties]

*Running it*
[image: executing]

I would like to change the colour to green or something else, but cant find out how

Comment: JProgressBar wraps an OS-specific UI `ProgressBarUI`, that tries to match the look-and-feel of the platform. You might be able to override `getUI()` to provide your own user interface, or change the properties of the L&F.

Comment: yes, but how???

Comment: Please also provide the relevant code section, if possible try to give a minimal example. By doing so you greatly improve the quality of your questions. Also it seems you are using some kind of *GUI manager*, could you tell us what exactly you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instructional example.  It will modify 4 of the JProgressBar's colors.
Might be a little hard to see the text colors but here is an image of what to
expect. The bar is red on black and the text color is yellow and blue.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class JProgressBarTest {

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.BLACK);
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.RED);
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.YELLOW);
    UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.BLUE);
    final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    new JFrame() {
        {
            getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            getContentPane().add(progressBar);
            progressBar.setValue(50);
            progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setSize(400, 200);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    };
    }
}
```

Comment: Good showcase! However it may be possible that OP can not do much with it as he seems to use some kind of *GUI manager* and does possibly not know how to switch to a *code view*. Maybe we should also find out what he is using and then tell him how to switch so that he can use your code.